# How to delete all facebook posts using automated system?

Tags: facebook, imacros

The following imacro script seems to delete all my likes from facebook posts

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=likes
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:mrs<SP>_2fmu<SP>img<SP>sp_dg7yy3<SP>sx_80da2b
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:_54nh
```

Is there something like this for all the posts? I want to delete all my posts using some automated system

Comment: iMacros has the loop feature, that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this deletes one post with iMacro (on the current Facebook site). You can delete all of them using iMacro's loop button.

Before launching the script, visit: `https://www.facebook.com/<YOUR-USERNAME>/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_11` and scroll down to load some posts.

`VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
' Select "delete" for the first post
TAG POS={{!loop}} TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Allowed on Timeline"
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS={{!loop}}  TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
' Confirm the deletion
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=class:_s ATTR=TXT:Delete<SP>Post
WAIT SECONDS=3`

Comment: I am getting an error: "RuntimeError: element I specified by CLASS:mrs<SP>_2fmu<SP>img<SP>sp_dg7yy3<SP>sx_80da2b was not found, line 8 (Error code: -921)"

Comment: Hi Alastor, the Facebook site changes from time to time. This should be more resilient to those changes

Comment: Thanks. I ended up reading the syntax and making my own macro. Deleted everything uptil 2010 using that. :)

Comment: @AlastorMoody do you mind sharing that? I'd like to delete everything before 2014... :) Thanks!